# Non-iCloud backup/export of WhatsApp chats

Tags: ios, whatsapp.app

WhatsApp doesn’t “natively” allow iOS users to back-up (the term here is rather export) their chat histories to any destination other than iCloud.

For my specific need, I need to have these chats in a readable, or at least recoverable format elsewhere other than iCloud.

There are several services, mainly MacOS apps, that claim to be able to extract this kind of data, however I am very wary of anything that isn’t “stamped” by an authority.

So, how can I export my WhatsApp chats outside of the app and to a file/folder on my HD? Bonus points for readable format.